# LIKE function on MySQL not picking up similar words

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I am currently using db-fiddle.com to practice my SQL code.

I have two tables.

'Customers':

| Customers_id | PracticeName | Location | PracticeType | Subref |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hermitage Vets | Essex | Farm | P030022 |
| 2 | West End Vets | Edinburgh | Companion | P030023 |

'Samples':

| Samples_id | Subref | SampleType | det | FAM | VIC | Gel_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P030022_1 | SWAB | MHYPCR | 38.72 | 35.00 | null |
| 2 | P030022_2 | SWAB | MHYPCR | 34.23 | 30.05 | null |
| 3 | P030022_3 | SWAB | MHYPCR | 34.00 | 29.99 | null |
| 4 | P030022_4 | SWAB | MHYPCR | 30.00 | 37.10 | null |

(There are more subref samples and more columns in Samples but I didn't want to clutter the page.)

There can be multiple samples as part of one subref that is why I made them two tables with the underscore to define results per sample.

I want to be able to see all the samples that are part of the Subref next to PracticeName. So the end result is the Samples table but with the PracticeName column attached.

*Sorry if this is not the best way to format things but I am a very new beginner.*

I tried both these codes, which apparently executed but nothing showed up in the results:

`SELECT * FROM Customers, Samples WHERE Customers.Subref LIKE (Samples.Subref + '%');`

`SELECT * FROM Customers, Samples WHERE Customers.Subref LIKE concat (Samples.Subref, '%');`

I have also tried creating another table to do many-to-many queries but again it executed with no results :

```
  Customers_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  , Samples_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  , PRIMARY KEY pk_Customers2Samples (Customers_id, Samples_id)
);
```

```
WHERE Customers.Subref like 'Samples.Subref%';
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any advice appreciated, please be nice.

Comment: which db  you are really using???

Comment: 1) the samples.subref should not have the postfix, like `_1`. If the subref values in both tables were the same, then joining would be simple. This is how you should do this. 2) customers.subref is the shorter field, so that should be on the right hand side of the like operator along with the wildcard.

Comment: I am using mySQL.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Samples, Customers WHERE Samples.Subref LIKE (Customers.Subref + '%');        does executes with no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to yourdata sample .. due the repsence of _n at the end yous houdl use the inverse
(match for string from customers + % like the string in samples)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Samples ON  Samples.Subref LIKE concat (Customers.Subref, '%')
```

the string for Sample in your data containg more chats respect the value in customers then can't macth .. the opposite should work

Comment: is there a way to avoid all columns in Customers from joining?

Comment: Your comment is not clear ..  if you want select only some columns you can use a selective select clause .. select sample.*  or select samples.your_col, customers.another_col